# Why does one piece of code overrides the other?

Tags: javascript, css

The problem with my code is that if the green element executes first the orange element cannot be executed. The orange works fine before the green one executes. I want the orange part to work after the green as well even if the green was pressed before.

```
function showToast() {
    const empty = document.getElementById("latitude" && "longitude" && "radius").value == "";
    var element = document.getElementById("applybutton");
    const message = empty ?
    "Geofence perimeter cannot be set due to missing configuration \n \n Kindly update all fields
     accordingly":
    "Geofence perimeter has been correctly set. \n \n Hence you may now proceed with Geofence Activation"
    + element.classList.add("green"); // THIS PART OVERRIDES THE ONE BELOW


    window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions({
        message: message,
        duration: "short",
        position: "top"
    });
}

function bin() {
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = "";
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = "";
    document.getElementById("radius").value = "";

    var element = document.getElementById("applybutton");
    element.classList.add("orange"); // THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK IF THE ONE UP WAS EXECUTED BEFORE
}
```

Comment: The CSS rule that defines `.green` probably has a higher specificity than `.orange`. Please post your CSS.

Comment: .orange{
    --background :#ec6800;
    width:40%;
}

.green{
    --background :#448303;
    width: 40%;
}

Comment: What do you mean by removing the green class or orange? Is there a way i can do it?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code, can you fix them and update the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause of the problem is in the second **classList.add** statement.
It is only adding the 'orange' style to a button that is already set to have 'green' style.

The problem can be fixed by ***explicitly removing all styles before adding a new one***

```
element.classList.remove("green", "orange")  // Remove all styles

element.classList.add("orange")   // Add orange style.
```

**More information:**
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp